# Jenkins Build Execute Shell - File Permission denied

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, jenkins

Trying to set up a simple NodeJS project with Jenkins and AWS EC2.

Jenkins runs on push. But will always fail on the build step. This is my build command:

```
npm install
./script/test
./script/deploy
```

Which gave me the error:

```
+ ./script/test
/tmp/jenkins10867859339292112280.sh: 3: ./script/test: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I add `chmod 777 ./script/test` before calling `./script/test/` it works for the test file.:

```
+ chmod 777 ./script/test
+ ./script/test

[90m․[0m

[92m [0m[32m 1 passing[0m[90m (28ms)[0m
```

If I now add `chmod 777 ./script/deploy` is does not work for the deploy file:

```
+ chmod 777 ./script/deploy
+ ./script/deploy
/tmp/jenkins10865500977174113561.sh: 6: ./script/deploy: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Now my build command looks like:

```
npm install
chmod 777 ./script/test
./script/test
chmod 777 ./script/deploy
./script/deploy
```

The test file works but now the deploy file is not found.

I tried to see if I can found it right before with a command `ls -l ./script/deploy` which gave me this result:

```
+ chmod 777 ./script/deploy
+ ls -l ./script/deploy
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 338 Aug  4 18:31 ./script/deploy
+ ./script/deploy
/tmp/jenkins11221280265482222163.sh: 7: ./script/deploy: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This result seems like it can find the file, but when calling it. It can not.

Test file:

```
#!/bin/sh
./node_modules/.bin/_mocha ./test/test.js
```

Deploy File:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -i JenkinsKey ubuntu@172.31.76.179 <<EOF
    cd ~/3DViewer
    git pull origin master
    curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    nvm install v16.6.1
    npm install
    npm install -g nodemon pm2
    pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js
    exit
EOF
```

Can provide my build log if needed.

Comment: I can't see what's going wrong here, but I would not use 3 build commands, but pack them together into a single script, say `buildscript`, which includes _install_, _test_ and _deploy_, and  then will be called from jenkins by `sh -x ./scripts/buildscript`. This gives you a bit more control over what's going on.

Comment: @user1934428 That did actually work, but I would like to have Jenkins fail if the test failed, and not have it deploy a failed test build.

Comment: Then test in your script, wheter ./script/test failed, and execute deploy only if it did not fail. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with absolute path of the file, if its in workspace try using

```
/bin/bash ${workspace}/script/deploy
```

else try with

```
/bin/bash <path of your script directory>/script/deploy
```

Comment: This work! Thank you!

I used `/bin/bash ${WORKSPACE}/script/deploy`

My working code is:
`npm install
/bin/bash ${WORKSPACE}/script/test
/bin/bash ${WORKSPACE}/script/deploy`